# Can I accumulate gcov line counts? (I don't have LCOV)

Tags: c++, gcov, test-coverage

The gcov data files (*.gcda) accumulate the counts across multiple tests.  That is a wonderful thing.  The problem is, I can't figure out how to get the .gcov files to accumulate in the same way the .gcda files do.

I have a large project (53 header, 54 cpp) and some headers are used in multiple cpp files.  The following example is radically simplified; the brute force approach will take days of manual, tedious work if that is required.

Say for example I have `xyz.hpp` that defines the xyz class.  On line 24 it defines the `build()` method that builds xyz data, and on line 35 it defines the `data()` method that returns a reference to the data.

Say I run my test suite, then I execute gcov on `abc.cpp`.  The `xyz.hpp.gcov` report has a count of 5 for line 24 (build) and a count of zero for line 35 (data).  Now I run gcov on `def.cpp`, and the `xyz.hpp.gcov` report has a count of zero for line 24 and a count of 7 for line 35.  So, instead of accumulating the report information and having a count of 5 for line 24 (build) and 7 for line 35 (data), it *replaces* the `xyz.hpp.gcov` each time so all counts are reset.  I understand why that's the default behavior, but I can't seem to override it.  If I'm unable to accumulate the .gcov reports programatically, I'll be forced to manually compare, say, a dozen different `xyz.hpp.gcov` in order to assess the coverage.

It looks like LCOV is able to do this accumulation, but it takes **weeks** to get new software installed in my current work culture.

Thanks in advance for any help.